# How to add filter when i convert current lead?

Tags: lightning

My question is when I use lightning standard convert button to convert the lead,I have to check few fields,exp:when the state,country fields are empty,I can't convert this lead.How can I add some requirements before convert action?Thank you guys,Help me!^_^

Comment: My mission is to overwrite a classic convert button.classic button use javascript to check those required fields,and redirect to standard convert jsp.But I don't know how to do it in lightning...

Comment: Please [edit] your question when adding details, instead of comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by validation rule.

```
 OR( ISBLANK(City), ISBLANK(State) )&& IsConverted
```